What's *"take up"* mean in *"Nietzsche's ideas were subsequently **taken up** and re-interpreted"*
This context is a part of the Wikipedia page about the philosophical concept of the Eternal return.
"Nietzsche's ideas were subsequently taken up and re-interpreted by other writers, such as Russian esotericist P. D. Ouspensky, who argued that it was possible to break the cycle of return."
Does take up in this context mean...


: to accept or adopt as one's own
took up the life of a farmer


In this case, the writers started believing in Nietzsche's ideas (as if they were their own).


: to proceed to consider or deal with
take up one problem at a time


In this case, the writers started to work on and develop Nietzsche's ideas.


to begin again or take over from another
we must take the good work up again


In this case, the writers took over the work of developing ideas from Nietzsche.
...?
(All the definitions come from the Merriam-Webster Dictionary)

"Taken up" in this context means that Nietzsche’s ideas were adopted for further discussion, exploration, or critical analysis. Writers like Ouspensky engaged with the concept of eternal return by critically examining it and offering their interpretations, rather than passively accepting it.

're-interpret' means it was beginning to be interpreted again where the last ones left off. Of the three definitions, the no. 3 looks like the most suitable definition among them.

Interesting. At first glance I was sure it was #1, adopted. I still think that; a new idea can be both adopted and re-interpreted (in the sense of building on that idea, or applying it to new contexts). But I can see the other arguments. This is all literary interpretation, not grammar.

Nietzsche's ideas were subsequently taken up by other writers.= borrowed and used by them

There's not a firm division between the three meanings. You can start believing in something but also develop it, either with or without Nietzsche's help. If you want to understand the passage, and the precise relationship between Nietzsche and Ouspensky, read up on these thinkers, don't expect a dictionary to explain the exact relationship between them.

When we "take up" ideas, we engage them critically.  The verb admits a wide range of possibilities: development, refutation, promotion, vilification, adaptation, and so on.

@Stuart F I expect from the people on this forum to answer only based on the context I provide. They don't have to be informed about this area to answer the question. I just want them to use their language knowledge to tell me which of these definitions are possible for a sentence like this, regardless of which of them are actually meant here. Also if I didn't provide some probable definitions I would be glad to here them too.

Yes, these senses.  As is often the case in lists of meanings from dictionaries, some of the senses are "close" and the use of a word doesn't fall exactly in one sense or another, but in a region of meaning that includes all of those.
So "yes" other writers started believing in some of Nietzsche's ideas, and they started to work on those ideas, ultimately taking over the development from Nietzsche (since by this time he was dead).  If you want more details on exactly what Ouspensky believed and how he developed the ideas, you'll won't find the answer in a dictionary.
